# Soketi with Laravel in different domains

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket

I'm trying to use real-time notifications using Soketi

So I createg the Soketi server in one separeted server with nodejs on port 6001 and SSL using letsencrypt.

Then I Created the notification

Added the JS script to layout:

```
 Echo.private('App.User.' + {{Auth::id()}})
        .notification((data) => {
         console.log(data);
        });
```

Added the this code compiled in layout too:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_PORT,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

So when I was in development ambient the notifications cakes properly, sended by one server without SSL (http://sede.inoprime.com.br), but when I was on production server It not work and this server has SSL and its diferent from Soketi server.
Application Laravel (https://trackerprime.inoprime.com.br)
Soketi Server (https://servicos.inoprime.com.br)

I found this two diferences when the aplications calls the websocket link: wss://servicos.inoprime.com.br:6001/app/app-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&flash=false

In development the response is:

```
{event: "pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded", channel: "private-App.User.1"}
```

In Production I got:

```
{
"event": "pusher:connection_established",
"data": "{"socket_id":"8565042074.5045547206","activity_timeout":30}"
}
```

Anyone have any idea what they might be getting?